# How do I change the x axis with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

R noob here, my data set has a numerical variable called agegrp and it ranges from 1-7.

I'm trying to plot a histogram using the following code

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=agegrp)) + geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth = 0.5)
```

But the x-axis only contains 2, 4, 6. What do I add/ change so that it shows 1-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
#Code
ggplot(data, aes(x=agegrp)) +
  geom_histogram(colour="black", binwidth = 0.5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,7,by=1))
```